# How to make filtering non model data in flask-admin

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I have to make dashboard like view in flask-admin that will use data retrieved from external API. I have already written a functions that get date ranges and return data from that range. I should use `BaseView` probably but I don't know how to actually write it to make filters work. This is example function that i have to use: `charts =  generate_data_for_dashboard('164', '6423FACA-FC71-489D-BF32-3A671AB747E3', '2018-03-01', '2018-09-01')`. Those params should be chosen from 3 different dropdowns. So far I know only how to render views with pre coded data like this :

```
class DashboardView(BaseView):

    kwargs = {}

    @expose('/', methods=('GET',))
    def statistics_charts(self):
        user = current_user
        company = g.company
        offices = Office.query.filter_by(company_id=company.id)
        self.kwargs['user'] = user
        self.kwargs['company'] = company
        charts =  generate_data_for_dashboard('164', '6423FACA-FC71-489D-BF32-3A671AB747E3', '2018-03-01', '2018-09-01')
        self.kwargs['chart1'] = charts[0]
        self.kwargs['chart2'] = charts[1]

        return self.render('stats/dashboard.html', **self.kwargs)
```

But I need some kind of form to filter it. In addition date filter dropdown should have dynamic options : `current_week, last_week, current_month, last_month, last_year`. Don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [WTForms](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to build a form. You then have to decide if you want the data to be fetched on Submit or without a reload of the page. In the former case,  you can just return the fetched information on the response page [in your statistics_charts view](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/forms.html#using-forms). But if you want the data to update without a reload, you'll need to use JavaScript to track the form field changes, send the AJAX request to the API, and then interpret the resulting JSON and update your dashboard graphs and tables as needed.

I have not used it, but this tutorial says you can use [Dash](https://alysivji.github.io/reactive-dashboards-with-dash.html) for substantial parts of this task, while mostly writing in Python. So that could be something to check out. There is also [flask_jsondash](https://github.com/christabor/flask_jsondash) which might work for you.